# Android NDK OpenSSL

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, android-ndk, openssl

I am new in NDK, I am trying to add openssl to my android project using C, I have looked and tried and I cannot figure out how to linked openssl libraries in Android, another reason I am asking this is because most page and post I've found that talk or say information about it don't say anything for 64 bit arch's(ARM64, MIPS64 and x86_64), only for ARM and X86 arch's, I haven't found any recent post using NDK 10 and 64 bit arch.

I tried this [link](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) and I get an error when I try the line:

`$ . ./setenv-android.sh`

`bash: ./setenv-android.sh: line 106: do`

the 106 line says:

```
for host in "linux-x86_64" "linux-x86" "darwin-x86_64" "darwin-x86"
  do
    if [ -d "$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/$_ANDROID_EABI/prebuilt/$host/bin" ]; then
    ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/$_ANDROID_EABI/prebuilt/$host/bin"
    break
  fi
done
```

but I don't know how to fix the code, and it kind of old that post.

Also I tried this [link](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android) but I couldn't make the step 1. `gpg --import # paste PGP public key block on stdin`
When I tried it with the corresponding public key block it didn't do something and when trying `./import_openssl.sh import openssl-*.tar.gz` it show an error and  `./import_openssl.sh regenerate patches/*.patch` didn't fix it also didn't know how to modify `openssl.config` and `patches` and also I don't think that work for 64 bit arch.

Can sombody tell me or send me how to linked openssl libraries in NDK for all ABI, I am using Windows 7, Cygwin, and NDK 10d

Comment: Well, it looks OK to me. It seems to be one f two things. First, ensure you are using Unix/Linux newline (`LF`), and not Windows (`CRLF`) or OS X (`CR`). Second, add a semi colon after `for host in "linux-x86_64" "linux-x86" "darwin-x86_64" "darwin-x86";`. The odd thing is the semi-colon should only be required if the `do` was on the same line as the `if`. (BTW, I wrote that script. I may have crossed Windows and OS X because I work on both platforms regularly).

Comment: I change the Unix/Linux newline (LF) and it works, thanks, but I'm getting 2 errors when I make the command `make depend`: `cryptlib.c:170:3: error: # error "Inconsistency between crypto.h and cryptlib.c"` cryptlib.c:170:3 says `#if CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS != 41
# error "Inconsistency between crypto.h and cryptlib.c"
#endif` and the other error `uid.c:77:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
 #include OPENSSL_UNISTD`

Comment: Start a new thread for the issue with `#errors`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve partially my problem but it's not completely answer, I did compile openssl for android x86 and arm architecture in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970094/android-ndk-openssl-error-cross-compiling) I post my advances.

I'm not going to mark this answer as correct till I'll compile openssl for all architectures

**EDIT**:

I post the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29970094/android-ndk-openssl-error-cross-compiling/30158725#30158725)

Comment: You question was related to errors running the script. Your answer was *"I changed the Unix/Linux newline (LF) and it works"*. You should provide the answer in this block; and then mark it as accepted. Don't change the question or leave it open. If you have a new question, then you should ask a new question. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: But the question was about cross-compiling libraries for android, the change to Unix newline(LF) fix one problem, but I got new problems aftert that and I "fixed" those new problem but the final product (cross-compiling in all android abi) it's not finish, I don't think I should provide the answer on this block yet, I am close to get the openssl .so libraries for all abi in android (that's the main objetive in this question), when I finnish I'll post my answer and close this thread but I don't want to give and incomplete answer