# Android NDK OpenSSL error cross-compiling

Tags: c, windows, android-ndk, openssl, cross-compiling

I am new in NDK and I am following this [guide](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) to build OpenSSL for Android, I am using Windows 7 and Cygwin for this.

I'm having errors when trying to build the OpenSSL library.

```
# From the 'root' directory
$ . ./setenv-android.sh
$ cd openssl-1.0.1g/

$ perl -pi -e 's/install: all install_docs install_sw/install: install_docs install_sw/g' Makefile.org
$ ./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp no-hw no-engine --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/$ANDROID_API

$ make depend
$ make all
```

When I try the `make depend` command I have 2 errors:

`cryptlib.c:171:3: error: #error "Inconsistency between crypto.h and cryptlib.c"
 # error "Inconsistency between crypto.h and cryptlib.c"`

the cryplib.c line 171 says:

```
#if CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS != 41
# error "Inconsistency between crypto.h and cryptlib.c"
#endif
```

I don't know how to fix that error.

the other one is `uid.c:77:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
 #include OPENSSL_UNISTD`

if I change the line 77 in uid.c to `#include <unistd.h>` I get an error in the Makefile, so I don't know if it's the way to fix it, the error was in depend Makefile.

```
depend:
    @[ -z "$(THIS)" -o -f buildinf.h ] || touch buildinf.h # fake buildinf.h if it does not exist
    @[ -z "$(THIS)" ] || $(MAKEDEPEND) -- $(CFLAG) $(INCLUDE) $(DEPFLAG) -- $(PROGS) $(LIBSRC)
    @[ -z "$(THIS)" -o -s buildinf.h ] || rm buildinf.h
    @[ -z "$(THIS)" ] || (set -e; target=depend; $(RECURSIVE_MAKE) )
    @if [ -z "$(THIS)" ]; then $(MAKE) -f $(TOP)/Makefile reflect THIS=$@; fi
```

Another question is if I can use this guide to build the OpenSSL library to the 64bit arch. (x86_64, arm64 and mips64) I haven't found information about OpenSSL for Android in those architectures, all post about it are old and those arch didn't exist for Android

## **EDIT**

I found a way to solve partially my problem (not the best one but it works), the problem was due some errors in some paths, because I was trying to use Cywin on Windows and some files(I don't which ones) were trying to reach some paths that doesn't exist because I was on Windows and not in Linux, so I just install Ubuntu on a virtual machine and try this [guide](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) again, and I could compile libraries and I have libcrypto.a libcrypto.so libssl.a libssl.so for Android ARM, x86, mips, ARM64 and x86_64  Architectures.

But the libraries doesn't work for x86_64 and ARM64, when I try to compile a .c using the android.mk for x86_64 or arm64 eabi it doesn't compile due some compatibility errors, but if a try to compile de same .c file withe the "x86_64" or "arm-64" for a x86 or arm eabi it does compile, so they are still a 32bit libraries, this is not the answer because I need the libraries for all the architecture (at least for armv5, armv7, armv8-64, x86, x86_64), this is just a small step.

I will be updating to help someone with the same problem and if someone want to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [guide](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android) and modifying the file  `setenv-android.sh` you can easy compile openssl for arm, x86 and mips.

You just have to modify `_ANDROID_NDK _ANDROID_ARCH _ANDROID_EABI _ANDROID_API` parameters

**note**: for mips you'll have to add some lines in the file around

around line 120:

```
 arch-mips)   
  ANDROID_TOOLS="mipsel-linux-android-gcc mipsel-linux-android-ranlib mipsel-linux-android-ld"
;;
```

around line 200:

```
if [ "$_ANDROID_ARCH" == "arch-mips" ]; then
   export MACHINE=mipsel
   export RELEASE=2.6.37
   export SYSTEM=android
   export ARCH=mips
   export CROSS_COMPILE="mipsel-linux-android-"
fi
```

if you follow the guide you'll have libcrypto.a, libssl.a, libcrypto.so and libssl.so.

if you want the libraries for 64 bits architecture you can do a pull from a device using adb, all android device have libcrypto.so and libssl.so in `/system/lib64` for 64bits version (only in a 64bits device), and `/system/lib` the 32bits version, you can use an emulator for that, if you can want the 64bits version of the static libraries (libcrypto.a and libssl.a) in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/wOPpHEivHTk) you can find the way to do it.

Comment: You really should use the site as intended. That's one question for one problem. When you move the question around, it creates a bunch of irrelevant answers that pretty much makes the question and old answers useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

> When I try the make depend command I have 2 errors:
>
> ```
> cryptlib.c:171:3: error: #error "Inconsistency between crypto.h and cryptlib.c"
> # error "Inconsistency between crypto.h and cryptlib.c"
> ```

There's a problem with the symlinks. Unpack the tarball again with `tar zxvf`. Then, verify the header files are *not* 0 length.

Also see [Inconsistency between crypto.h and cryptlib.c](https://marc.info/?l=openssl-dev&m=101152147105961) on the OpenSSL mailing list. And [How to copy symbolic link file from Linux to Windows and then back to Linux but still keeping it as a symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23380231/608639) on Stack Overflow.